# Browser cannot get cookies from Rails App on wsl2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04

My Application is created by RoR on Ubuntu 22.04 on wsl2. I can access it from browser on windows, but cannot login because browser doesn't store cookies.

My app marked cookies as lax, and when I changed it to :none, browser displayed warning about CORS.
My app doesn't have anything special, and I accessed it as localhost. When I started to same app on Mac. I can access it nominally.

What does occur to my app? Do I need some special settings for it?

Comment: Is the session-cookie being set?

Comment: session cookie isn't set, but App sends it certainly.